# Unique Substrings in wrap around strings

Tags: string, algorithm

I have been given an infinite wrap around of the string *str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"*  so it looks like 
**"..zabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd...."** and another string *p*.

I need to find out ***how many unique non-empty substrings of p are present in the infinite wraparound string str?***

```
For example: "zab"
There are 6 substrings "z", "a", "b", "za", "ab", "zab" of string "zab" in str.
```

I tried finding all suffixes of p in a particular concatenation of the string *str* say for example: *"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"*

and as soon as i get a suffix which is a part of the above i add all its substrings to my result, as:

```
         for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
             String suffix = p.substring(i,length);
             if(isPresent(suffix)) {
                 sum += (suffix.length()*(suffix.length()+1))/2;
                 break;
             } else {
                 sum++;
             }
         }
```

And my isPresent function is:

```
     private boolean isPresent(String s) {
            if(s.length()==1) {
                return true;
            }
            String main = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde
fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            return main.contains(s);

        }
```

If the length of p is greater than my assumed concatenated string assumed in isPresent function, my algorithm fails!!

So how should i find the substrings irrespective of the the wrap around string *str*? Is there a better approach for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas/suggestions (not a full algo)

1. you don't need to consider an infinite repetition of the wrap around string but only `len(p)/len(repeating-fragment) + 1` (integral division) repetitions. Let's denote this string with `S` ******
2. if a substring `sp` of `p` is a substring of `S`, than any substrings of `sp` will be substrings of `S`

So the problem seems to reduce to:

- find `sp` (substring of both `p` and `S`) with the maximal length. This is called [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) and admits a dynamic programming solution with the complexity of `O(n*m)` (lengths of the two strings). The cited has a pseudo-code algo.
- repeat the above recursively with the 'remnants' of `p` after eliminating the longest common substring.

Now, you have a sequence of "longest common substrings". How many do you need to retain? I feel that the "longest common substring" may be used to trim down the need of brute-forcing every substring of any and all the above, but I'd need more time than I have available now.

I hope the sketch above helps.

---

****** I might be wrong on the number of repetitions which need to be considered. If I am, then in any case there will be a maximal number of repetitions to be considered and there will be an `S` of minimal length that is sufficient for the purpose.